# WHM Server receiving lots of "FAILED: cphulk"

Tags: linux, cpanel, whm

I have a WHM server on GoDaddy.
I'm receiving quite a lot (3-4 a day) mails about a process failing and recovering itself. Happens mostly to "cphulkd" but also to "lfd".
My server:
WHM version v68.0.33. Contains two websites (One Moodle and one Wordpress). 2GB Ram, 60GB HD.

This is the whole mail:

> Server    s50-62-22-123.secureserver.net Primary IP Address
>     50.62.22.123 Service Name   cphulkd Service Status  failed ⛔ Notification   The service “cphulkd” appears to be down. Service Check
>   Method    The system’s command to check or to restart this service
>   failed. Number of Restart Attempts    1 Service Check Raw Output  (XID
>   ejd2e7) The “cphulkd” service is down.
>
> The subprocess “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_cphulkd” reported
>   error number 255 when it ended. Startup Log   Starting cPHulkd...
>   Started. Starting PID 3789: cPhulkd - processor - dormant mode -
>   accepting connections Memory Information   Used   2.43 GB Available
>     1.57 GB Installed   4 GB Load Information   0.17 0.19 0.18 Uptime   2 days, 18 hours, 59 minutes, and 37 seconds IOStat Information
>     avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
>              0.62    0.11    0.12    0.17    0.00   98.99 Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn Top Processes
>   PID   Owner   CPU %   Memory %    Command 18850   root    2.45    2.29    spamd
>   child 3452    root    0.94    2.35
>     /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/524/bin/perl -T -w
>   /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/spamd --max-spare=1 --max-children=3
>   --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1,::1 --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --listen=5 1488  mysql   0.52    7.49    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr
>   --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=s50-62-22-179.secureserver.net.err --open-files-limit=10000 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/s50-62-22-179.secureserver.net.pid 18854     dovecot     0.31    0.06    dovecot/auth 20291  root    0.07    0.71    lfd -
>   sleeping

Any ideas?
What's weird is that the mail says I have 4GB but I only have 2GB..

Comment: Can you provide more details about the email that you receive? That's most probably the email subject but additional information can be found in the email. That could be helpfull

Comment: I added the mail in the question, thanks!

Comment: Did you try a forced cpanel update? `/script/upcp --force` then do a `yum -y update` and then reboot the server? Most of the time, a cPanel/WHM update fixes a lot of stuff... to see the exact server's memory you could issue a `free -m` and see what it shows